# querydsl-jpa 3.7.3 error when used with spring-data-jpa 1.10.0

Tags: spring-data-jpa, querydsl

I'm using

```
<groupId>com.mysema.querydsl</groupId>
<artifactId>querydsl-jpa</artifactId>
<version>3.7.3</version>
```

no problem with

```
<groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
<version>1.9.4.RELEASE</version>
```

instead using

```
<groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
<version>1.10.1.RELEASE</version>
```

on the same code I've the following errors:

```
[ERROR] /C:/Prj/Java/Eclipse/Elfolab/src/main/java/com/interlabsrl/elfolab/persistence/multiple/repository/elettroforesi/springdatajpa/LinguaRepository.java:[13,8] cannot access com.querydsl.core.types.OrderSpecifier
  class file for com.querydsl.core.types.OrderSpecifier not found
[ERROR] /C:/Prj/Java/Eclipse/Elfolab/src/main/java/com/interlabsrl/elfolab/controller/ricercaPaziente/RicercaPazienteController.java:[487,33] cannot access com.querydsl.core.types.Predicate
  class file for com.querydsl.core.types.Predicate not found
[ERROR] /C:/Prj/Java/Eclipse/Elfolab/src/main/java/com/interlabsrl/elfolab/controller/ricercaArchivio/RicercaArchivioController.java:[74,32] no suitable constructor found for QSort(com.mysema.query.types.OrderSpecifier<java.util.Date>)
    constructor org.springframework.data.querydsl.QSort.QSort(com.querydsl.core.types.OrderSpecifier<?>...) is not applicable
      (varargs mismatch; com.mysema.query.types.OrderSpecifier<java.util.Date> cannot be converted to com.querydsl.core.types.OrderSpecifier<?>)
    constructor org.springframework.data.querydsl.QSort.QSort(java.util.List<com.querydsl.core.types.OrderSpecifier<?>>) is not applicable
      (argument mismatch; com.mysema.query.types.OrderSpecifier<java.util.Date> cannot be converted to java.util.List<com.querydsl.core.types.OrderSpecifier<?>>)
[ERROR] /C:/Prj/Java/Eclipse/Elfolab/src/main/java/com/interlabsrl/elfolab/controller/ricercaArchivio/RicercaArchivioController.java:[611,31] no suitable constructor found for QSort(com.mysema.query.types.OrderSpecifier<java.lang.String>)
    constructor org.springframework.data.querydsl.QSort.QSort(com.querydsl.core.types.OrderSpecifier<?>...) is not applicable
      (varargs mismatch; com.mysema.query.types.OrderSpecifier<java.lang.String> cannot be converted to com.querydsl.core.types.OrderSpecifier<?>)
    constructor org.springframework.data.querydsl.QSort.QSort(java.util.List<com.querydsl.core.types.OrderSpecifier<?>>) is not applicable
      (argument mismatch; com.mysema.query.types.OrderSpecifier<java.lang.String> cannot be converted to java.util.List<com.querydsl.core.types.OrderSpecifier<?>>)
```

Any idea about what's wrong between these versions?

EDIT:

Using

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
        <artifactId>querydsl-jpa</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

i still have these errors:

```
C:\Prj\Java\Eclipse\Elfolab\src\main\java\com\interlabsrl\elfolab\persistence\multiple\repository\elettroforesi\table\custom\impl\MetodicaRepositoryImpl.java:11: error: package com.mysema.query.jpa.impl does not exist
import com.mysema.query.jpa.impl.JPAQuery;
```

Answer (score 7):

Instead of

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.mysema.querydsl</groupId>
    <artifactId>querydsl-*</artifactId>
    <version>3.7.3</version>
</dependency>
```

you should use now

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
    <artifactId>querydsl-*</artifactId>
    <version>4.1.3</version>
</dependency>
```

The packages inside the jar files also have been changed so you have to change imported querydsl classes in your source code.

Answer (score 2):

You should update the version of your querydsl to 4.1. Note that the groupId also have changed.

In [here](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.data/spring-data-jpa/1.10.1.RELEASE) you can see that the 1.10.1.RELEASE uses the 4.1 of querydsl and that could be interfering with you using an old version.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following configuration found(barely) [here](http://www.querydsl.com/static/querydsl/latest/reference/html/ch02.html)

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
  <artifactId>querydsl-apt</artifactId>
  <version>${querydsl.version}</version>
  <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
  <artifactId>querydsl-jpa</artifactId>
  <version>${querydsl.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

and for the maven plugin

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.mysema.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>apt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.3</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>process</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <outputDirectory>target/generated-sources/annotations</outputDirectory>
                <processor>com.querydsl.apt.jpa.JPAAnnotationProcessor</processor>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Even though the majority were moved to com.querydsl the plugin should currently still be com.mysema.